# ¿Qué argumento se debe colocar para completar un parámetro [object Page = Type.Missing]?

Tags: c#

Me encuentro trabajando en C# .Net, estoy creando una dll y estoy utilizando el método que muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que no puedo dejar el tercer parámetro sin argumento, pero no sé qué colocar, he intentado creando el siguiente objeto:

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
```

y lo he colocado como argumento, pero el error persiste.

Agradeceré mucho su gentil apoyo.

Gracias.

Comment: ese tercer argumento no es opcional?

Comment: En teoría, pero si lo dejo vacío me muestra error.

Comment: que error te muestra?

Comment: Subraya todo de rojo, y al colocar el cursor encima, dice que los argumentos no son válidos.

Comment: La definicion de la funcion escrita asi, implica que el parametro es opcional, y que si no viene, usa System.Type.Missing. Podrias pasar eso. No se de donde sale esa clase que estas usando...

Comment: Ya lo probé pasando el System.Type.Missing y el error persiste. La clase es de una dll que estoy utilizando, permite la comunicacion con el sistema que quiero manejar, se llama Interop.xxxxxx.dll

Comment: ¿qué hace esa función? ese dato ayudaría. Igual es un tipo lo que espera (por ejemplo gettype(Form)).